# Setting up scala with IntelliJ

Tags: java, macos, scala, intellij-idea

I have Intellij ultimate 11.1, with the scala plugin installed.

I installed scala 2.9.2 using homebrew, which put scala in:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.9.2>



>which scala
/usr/local/bin/scala
>scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.9.2 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL
```

Creating a new java module project, I get this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can someone help me fix these issues, why didn't the scala plugin make this work out of the box? :)

Comment: Which says that scala in `/usr/local/bin/scala` why do you telling that it is in Cellar?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You need to specify `/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.9.2/libexec` directory on your first screenshot. This is Mac `brew` specific, the same case is valid for `grails` installed via `brew`.

Standard [Scala distribution download](http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads/distrib/files/scala-2.9.2.tgz) has different layout which IDEA understands correctly, `brew` is creating `libexec` directory where it writes `/lib` and `/src` directories expected by IDEA.

Comment: thanks, now it says with a yellow sign "version 2.9.2, no doc/scala-devel-...", how do I fix that?

Comment: Download the documentation from http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads/distrib/files/scala-docs-2.9.2.zip, unpack in some directory, modify JavaDocs directory in the `scala-library` in IDEA module libraries to the directory where you have unpacked the documentation (this directory must have `scala` subdirectory with `.html` files.

Comment: I came here trying to find where I should download the docs for the scala download from the installation from the web site. I instead used brew to install it and then it tells you a scala home to use for IntelliJ.

Comment: Even with `brew install scala --with-docs` pointing at `libexec` will give you doc errors. Update your homebrew and then point at `/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.XX.X/idea` to get the doc errors to go away.

Answer (score 71):

***Updated for Intellij 11.1.5***

Here's a step by step for any of those who are trying to get Scala in IntelliJ up and running.

**Download Scala Plugin**

IntelliJ > Preferences > Plugins > Browse Repositories... > Scala
Click Ok and allow IntelliJ to restart

**Download Scala**

In Terminal enter

```
brew install scala --with-docs
```

**Setup symbolic links for IntelliJ discovery process**

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/scala/<version>/libexec/src /usr/local/Cellar/scala/<version>/src
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/scala/<version>/libexec/lib /usr/local/Cellar/scala/<version>/lib
mkdir -p /usr/local/Cellar/scala/<version>/doc/scala-devel-docs
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/scala/<version>/share/doc/scala /usr/local/Cellar/scala/<version>/doc/scala-devel-docs/api
```

**Create Project in IntelliJ**

Here you are going to create a Java project from scratch as you normally would.  However, in the last step, you will select Scala in the "Technologies" page.

In the **Use Scala Distribution** enter `/usr/local/Cellar/scala/<version>`

In the **Compiler** dropdown select `scala-compiler`

Click Ok and you are ready to create your first Scala object

For reference ->
http://scalacookbook.blogspot.com/2012/09/scala-for-intellij.html

Comment: This is great! When I follow this it also complains that there is no SDK. Where are the SDK folder?

Comment: If my memory serves me correct, the SDK is still Java.  The Scala piece is still just a facet of the main project.  That is, there is no "pure" Scala project setup

Comment: Would it be worth updating this answer with "--use-docs" to get the documentation, then it'd be the authoritive answer for those who search for the answer?

Comment: Also, is it worth updating the brew formula to add in the symlinks automatically?

Comment: Good suggest about the --with-docs (use-docs).  I went ahead and changed this and updated some other items for 11.1.5.

Comment: on scala 2.11.6 and intellij 14.1 I had to do as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29841210/112440 and use the path  /usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.11.6/idea/lib

Answer (score 20):

The latest Brew has already realized this problem and created automatic symlinks upon installing Scala.

Firstly, install Scala with Documentation

```
brew install scala --with-docs
```

Secondly, provide the following path in IntelliJ

```
/usr/local/opt/scala/idea
```

Answer (score 16):

Rather than downloading the docs separately you can use the `--with-docs` option when installing scala with homebrew:

```
brew install scala --with-docs
```

Then in IntelliJ point your JavaDocs path in the scala-library to `/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.9.2/share/doc`.

Answer (score 7):

I'm just found another way to configure scala with intelJIdea.
If scala installed with brew then just write in terminal:

```
brew info scala
```

you will see smth like that:

```
scala: stable 2.11.4 (bottled)
http://www.scala-lang.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.11.4 (3401 files, 433M) *
  Built from source with: --with-docs
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/scala.rb
==> Options
--with-docs
    Also install library documentation
--with-src
    Also install sources for IDE support
==> Caveats
To use with IntelliJ, set the Scala home to:
  /usr/local/opt/scala/idea

Bash completion has been installed to:
  /usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d
```

Then just include `/usr/local/opt/scala/idea` into your idea config panel.

Comment: when I am installing should I be using `brew install scala --with-docs --with-src` or just `brew install scala`?

Answer (score 3):

Now is 2021 year. my (latest) environment is:

- `IntelliJ IDEA`: `IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3.2 (Community Edition)`
- `OS`: `macOS 10.14.6`

## Steps to setup Scala using IntelliJ IEA

### in Mac

- install scala using brew

  - `brew install scala`

### in IntelliJ

- install `Scala` plugin

  - `IntelliJ IDEA`->`Preferences`->`Plugins`->search: `scala`-> `Search in Marketplace`->`Install`->`Restart IDE`

    - [image]
- configure `Java JDK` + configure `Scala SDK`: when first time open `*.scala` file, will notice you:

  - **Project JDK is not defined**

    - click `Setup SDK` -> choose (your installed) `Java 11`

      - [image]
  - **No Scala SDK in module**

    - clcik `Setup Scala SDK`

      - `Add Scala Support`-> `Use library` -> `Create` -> `Select JAR's for the new Scala SDK` -> Click and choose `Brew` -> `OK`

        - [image]
      - `Add Scala Support`-> `Use library` -> (then) selected: **scala-sdk-2.13.5** -> `OK`

        - [image]

finally can happy debug scala (file's class's `main` function):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am using Yosemite, and the following worked for me.

```
brew install scala --with-docs
```

Then I tested IntelliJ by creating a new project, using the Java SDK, and for compiler putting in:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/[insertversion]/libexec
```

[Here is what I see in IntelliJ when I created a new project with these settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVYtd.png)

I tested compiling a Hello World program via [this](http://scala-lang.org/documentation/getting-started.html?_ga=1.254517771.2007423835.1445004857#your_first_lines_of_code) and it compiled correctly to the console.

Note, I ignored what @Zagorulkin said above even though it seems logical that if Homebrew is saying so my compile path should be different to the above.

Answer (score -2):

Change `/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.9.2` to `/usr/local/Cellar/scala/` and you are good to go.