# Scala GAE project - fail to compile in intellij

Tags: java, google-app-engine, scala, intellij-idea

i have a big GAE (Gooogle app engine) project in scala , and java in combinated. I have intellij 11 with the scala plugin.

I added the war exploded to the server configuration but when i try to compile, this fail.
My only clue is:

```
error while loading CrawlQuery, class file 'very/long/path/Foo.class' is broken
(Scala class file does not contain Scala annotation)
```

I checked the information, and looks like the problem is some anotation of @JsonTypeInfo: 
https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5165 fails in scala 2.9.1

I changed from 2.9.1 to 2.9.2 but does'nt work. (I'm downloaded a scala-compiler.2.9.2.jar and I added  to the project as a global library)

Also, i downloaded the scala library from http://www.scala-lang.org/node/309, and create a dummy project to set the as global library, like explain in: [Setting up scala with IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827017/setting-up-scala-with-intellij)

One of my friends use Eclipse to compile the same project, with the plugin http://scala-ide.org/ and work's for him.

Comment: The compilation fails, inclusive with the maven compiler, so we must to chage the workarround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After check some workarounds, our solutión was create an interface with the notation of the jackson, and add to the class as a mixint:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.MINIMAL_CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
public interface JsonTypeMixin {

}
```

and in the implementation:

```
 objectMapper.addMixInAnnotations(classOf[Post], classOf[JsonTypeMixin])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also tell IntelliJ to use the new Scala compiler you downloaded: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/download/attachments/12353606/new_project4.png

Comment: I configure as a global library. And i configure the main compiler as scala 2.9.2

Comment: This might be a bug. Try creating issue here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA