# How to configure Intellij 12 on Mac to find the scala libraries?

Tags: macos, scala, intellij-idea

NB: Marking this question as duplicate was faulty given it ignores the comment I made here in the OP:

From the OP: Yes there is a similar question [Setting up scala with IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827017/setting-up-scala-with-intellij) that answers a portion of this one  - particularly as relates to brew defined paths. But that but it pertains to IJ 11 for which the scala configuration is quite different.

I am missing some step to properly configure scala on OS X 10.8.4 for  IJ Ultimate 12.1.4. 
The following shows that scala has been installed (via brew):

```
mellyrn:~ steve$ brew install scala
Warning: scala-2.10.2 already installed
```

The scala compiler is set to 'external build':

[image]

Following screenshot shows interpreter is 'missing' the basic scala libraries:

[image]

Following shows the library missing in the scala facet:

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13716420/104891 for IDEA 12 configuration. Note that brew installation is different from what IDEA is expecting, but you already know it after reading the first link.

Comment: That other question is addressed to IJ11. Scala configuration has changed significantly since then. Please either review and update that question to cover IJ12 or answer here. Thanks!

Comment: @CrazyCoder. Thanks that is helpful.. but I have an existing project and am not creating a new one (scala project) from scratch. I am looking to make the added Scala facet (/ framework) work properly to an existing project.

Comment: Create a new dummy project, IDEA will add a library for you, make it a global one, then reuse this library in the existing project.

Comment: @CrazyCoder  Ok that sounds reasonable, will try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what works for me in intellij idea 12.1.4 community edition

- open Project Structure
- add a java library named "scala-library" which includes all the scala-*.jar in the lib directory of your scala installation
- in the scala facet -> Compiler library, select "scala-library" you just created in the dropdown list