# Setting up Scaladoc for IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

When creating a new Scala project using IntelliJ, i get the scaladoc warning.

How can this be rectified please?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting up scala with IntelliJ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827017/setting-up-scala-with-intellij), see [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827017/setting-up-scala-with-intellij#comment14122493_10828320).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll go ahead and answer my own question here

1. Navigate to [Scala download page](http://www.scala-lang.org/downloads#api) and download appropriate API
2. Unpack the archive and move contents into your Scala's installation (I ran sudo `mkdir scaladoc` to create `/Library/Scala/2.10.0-RC2/scaladoc`)
3. Update module to point to the right location

[image]

You can quickly verify installation by typing

```
object Main extends App {
}
```

Once you <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> on the `App`, you should see the scaladoc which matches the online version

[image]

Comment: What is your `Ctrl+J` mapped to?  My key bindings are different.

Comment: @KenWilliams I guess he's using Mac. If you're using Windows, use `Ctrl+Q`

Comment: Hovering the mouse over the class name is enough in the new IDEA