# Error: scala: No 'scala-library*.jar' in Scala compiler library

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, intellij-13

**Environment:** Play 2.3.0/Scala 2.11.1/IntelliJ 13.1

I used Typesafe Activator 1.2.1 to create a new project with Scala 2.11.1.  After the project was created, I ran `gen-idea`.  The generated IDEA project fails to compile with the error:

`Error: scala: No 'scala-library*.jar' in Scala compiler library in test`

Am I doing something wrong?  Workaround?

[image]

Comment: Apparently a workaround is to create a new IntelliJ scala project, select a scala home directory where 2.11 is installed, check the box to make sure it becomes a "global" library, close this project, go back to the original project, remove the facet, and re-add with the new global library.  ARGGHHHH... surely there is a better way.  I love the Scala language, but the brittleness of the tools just really makes me mad.

Comment: You don't need to use `gen-idea` task in IDEA 13.1. SBT support is now built-in. You just need to import SBT project via File/Import project menu item.

Comment: Perfect, Vladimir.  Even better than `gen-idea`.  You can make this the answer.

Comment: With the default pathway through the New Scala SBT Project pathway, I am receiving this error with IntelliJ 2017.2.5 Scala Plugin 2017.2.11.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since IDEA 13 you should use SBT support which is bundled with Scala plugin.

With it there is no need to add third-party SBT plugins and run special commands; just import the project using "File -> Import project..." menu item, and it will automatically load SBT project structure and its dependencies.

Comment: This solution is almost perfect.  IntelliJ seems to select Scala 2.10 as the language level in the Scala Facet, but has selected the 2.11 compiler.  Adjusting the language level to Scala 2.11 closes the loop here.

Comment: The built-in plugin does not work in some circumstances.  I frequently resort to sbt gen-idea.  It has to do with refreshing projects after the build.sbt has changed.

Comment: jkschneider's tip fixed build issues for org.spec2, fwiw

Comment: In case you're getting compilation errors right after importing the project, try close & reopen. Worked for me.

Comment: This is a solution too in case that you have the error `Error accessing ~/.m2/repository/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.11.8/scala-library-2.11.8.jar`

Answer (score 61):

1. Open File -> Project Structures -> Libraries, remove any scala sdk in it, e.g. scala-sdk-2.11.8 in the following image.
   [image]
2. Click on +, then Scala SDK.
   [image]
3. Select the right Scala SDK from the list, for me, it's Ivy-Scala-2.11.8 shown in the picture.[image]
4. Select the current project(mine is `spark-test`), click OK.
   [image]
5. Then click OK to close it.
   [image]
6. Run again, it should work now.

Comment: I tried this, but all the libraries in step 3 were ghosted out as disabled. I could not select any of them.

Comment: This worked but i have literally no idea what changed?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue with the .idea files generated by ./activator idea with play 2.3. A quick fix is to look in "Project Structure->modules" and note the name of the compiler library. For me it was "SBT: scala2.11.1". The look in "Project Structure->Libraries" and check the contents of this library. It should contain scala-compiler.jar, scala-library.jar, scala-reflect.jar. If this libraries are not present, add them (in my case they are located in ~/.sbt/boot/scala-2.11.1/lib).

Comment: Hi Russell, I have the exact same problem. So what is the bug that causes this? a problem with activator?

Comment: running ./activator idea causes the problem to re-appear after this fix so I suppose it is a bug with the activator's .idea file generation. I haven't raised it with the typesafe team myself. Perhaps someone should do so...

Answer (score 3):

it looks like my answer is 9 years late, but the previous answers didn't work for me when I faced such a problem, so I'll leave my solution here.

File > Project structure > Global Libraries > in my case it was scala-sdk-2.13.8 > press minus sign (remove library) > press plus sign > select SDK that corresponds to your scala version ( ex. scala-sdk-2.12.10 in my case \ find you version in pom.xml file) > OK > Applay\OK

[image]

Comment: For multi-module projects, make sure you choose all of your modules that will need the scala-sdk.  After doing this, my entire project compiled fine.

Answer (score 1):

For IDEA 15 and project exported from Activator 1.3.5 only Russell's solution helped at the moment.
I have fixed scala compiler library with adding 3 libraries located in ~/.sbt/boot/scala-2.11.1/lib to library's compiler classpath and classes. After indexing project I moved this library to global libraries of IDEA and it was saved there.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.

If you are building your project using external `sbt` i.e `sbt compile` then it will create or add dependencies in libraries(all external dependency also) and scala sdk will be added as `SBT:scala*` based on version of your scala.
So you can remove `SDK` with SBT as prefix and add proper SDK through Intellij.

```
File->Project Structure->Libraries
```

Remove SBT SDK and add it manually.

Answer (score 0):

For me with IDEA 12, I fixed this issue when I unchecked the box for "Use external build" in Settings.Compiler.

Answer (score 0):

now is 2021 year, in Mac, use IntelliJ to run scala:

- core logic

  - `Mac`: `brew install scala`
  - `IntelliJ`: open *.scala file, then according notice to auto config `java JDK` and `Scala SDK`
- detailed steps: pls refer [another post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827017/setting-up-scala-with-intellij/66560977#66560977)

Answer (score 0):

I'm an absolute Scala beginner.  I was wanting to get up and running. I needed to create a Scala *project*, not a Java project with Scala library:

[image: screenshot showing correct buttons to click]

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue for Maven multimodule project unexpectedly.

It happens with IntelliJ 2023.1.3.

Solution: simple re-import of Maven project helped.