# Multiple scala libraies causing error in intellij?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am using intellij 14 with scala 2.11.6 installed using home brew and symlink using

```
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.11.6/libexec/src /usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.11.6/src
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.11.6/libexec/lib  /usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.11.6/lib
mkdir -p /usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.11.6/doc/scala-devel-docs
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.11.6/share/doc/scala /usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.11.6/doc/scala-devel-docs/api
```

I tried running a simple hello world but run into the following issue.

```
Error:scalac: Multiple 'scala-library*.jar' files (scala-library.jar, scala-library.jar, scala-library.jar) in Scala compiler classpath in Scala SDK scala-sdk-2.11.6
```

Edit:

So I check the compiler class path on global libraries and apparently there are multiple scal-library.jar

```
file:///usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.11.6/idea/lib/scala-library.jar
file:///usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.11.6/lib/scala-library.jar
file:///usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.11.6/libexec/lib/scala-library.jar
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Did you have another version of scala installed on your system?

Comment: I did `brew uninstall scala` and `brew install scala with-docs`  don't know if that is causing the issue

Comment: Try Uninstalling scala from your system , run scala command if it show scala command not found that means it is completely un-installed, and then install it again.

Comment: yeah I tried `brew uninstall scala` again and run scala in terminal and it doesn't run scala, so I think there is no duplicates

Comment: SHIFT+CTRL+ALT+S, then remove the extra scala JARs from your library.  This assumes you are building from your IDE.

Comment: Where should I do the command? Do I keep the one in idea or lib or libexec?

Answer (score 62):

Maybe you have used

```
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.11.6/
```

as the path for Scala SDK?

When you install scala with homebrew that path will contain not only the scala libraries, but also a symlink with the relevant libraries for intellij. So if you use the top-level install directory intellij will find the libraries twice.

Instead you should use

```
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.11.6/idea/lib
```

Comment: how to change: File > Project Structure > Global Libraries > + > Scala SDK > Browse > choose /usr/local/Cellar/scala/your version/idea/lib

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue than you experimented and the solution, actually very easy, was actually erasing the .idea folder from the project, the problem is that the configuration inside of this folder (containing the set ups for example for the test, VCS, the runs, etc) gets corrupted with double entries (probably cos you update your Scala version), once you do this and reopen the project in Intellij the IDEA will generate a fresh new configuration for you.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me.
I'm using Idea 2019.2.2 and Windows 10.

In the folder `.idea/libraries/` I had two files: `sbt__org_scala_lang_scala_library_2_13_0_jar.xml` and `sbt__org_scala_lang_scala_library_2_13_0_jar2.xml`.

I deleted the second file.
Then I opend the first one and there were duplicate lines:

```
    <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/AppData/Local/Coursier/cache/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/jline/jline/2.14.6/jline-2.14.6.jar" />
    <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/AppData/Local/Coursier/cache/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.13.0/scala-compiler-2.13.0.jar" />
    <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/AppData/Local/Coursier/cache/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.13.0/scala-compiler-2.13.0.jar" />
    <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/AppData/Local/Coursier/cache/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.13.0/scala-library-2.13.0.jar" />
    <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/AppData/Local/Coursier/cache/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.13.0/scala-library-2.13.0.jar" />
    <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/AppData/Local/Coursier/cache/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.13.0/scala-reflect-2.13.0.jar" />
```

So I deleted duplicates and errors disappeared.
Hope this will help someone else.

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into that error. The fix I found was to remove the duplicate scala-library in the .iml file generated by intellij.

Basically I located the relevant .iml file by grepping the scala version, and found that two scala-library in that file. I removed the scala 2.11 version, and then it works.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the following line in build.sbt:

```
...

scalaVersion := "2.13.0"

...
```

Try rebuilding and running it again

Comment: Tried all answers above this one and only this worked for me. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

2019 update... I'm running Ubuntu Linux and IntelliJ community 2019.1 with sbt 2.13.1 and got the exact same error. I also found that if I built directly from sbt with "runMain package.MyClass" it worked, so I knew it must be an IntelliJ problem, not a "real" problem.

Anyway, I found the file .idea/libraries/sbt.. lots of crazy long name ... scala_library_2_13_1_jar.xml.

In it, there was an XML block , and in that block, two entries were duplicated:


I first noticed the scala-library one, and after deleting that, the error report came up about the scala-compiler duplicate too. 
After deleting both duplicates, my build is now working.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the problem go to project structure in intellij and go to global libraries
It should be like this[image]

After that remove all the scala SDKs by hitting the - mark

Next, click the + and choose your Scala SDK version to add

[image]

After that please make sure to apply the changes and re-run the program

Answer (score 0):

You have JAR files from multiple versions of `scala-library.jar`.  In order to make the error go away you will have to delete the duplicates.  To figure out which version you want to keep, you can view the manifest file inside each JAR:

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Inside the manifest file you should see something like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path:
Implementation-Title: Scala-Library
Implementation-Version: 2.11.4
```

The error is happening because IntelliJ cannot figure out which version of a given Scala class to use.

Answer (score 0):

Delete multiple versions of scala-library in sbt, leaving one.

Answer (score 0):

Having similar symptoms, but on a `Ubuntu` machine, not using `brew`:

I am using `/usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar` as launcher. To fix the mentioned problem, I've had to purge the directories 1) `project`, 2) `target` and 3) `.idea` of the relevant Scala projects, doing sbt refresh in IntelliJ (`View` - `Tool Windows` -> `sbt`, hit the `Reimport all sbt projects` icon), and rebuild all modules afterwards.

As a last step, when the error occurs further, switch over to Ubuntu shell / terminal, and do a `sbt clean compile` in the problematic project folder. Fix the compile issues if some are occuring. If this does not help, change `scalaVersion` in `build.sbt` e.g. from `2.12.9` to `2.12.8` (the error occurs more often with `2.12.9`), remove `scalaOrganization` definition (but keep `organization`). Repeat the `sbt refresh` of IntelliJ. OMG.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:
In IDEA

> Preferences -> Plugins -> Scala -> Update

Restart IDEA